# Optimizing PHP pagination

Tags: php, pagination

How do i make the option value to increase by one page if the database only display at least 5 row per page

lets say if the table has 20 row, the option value will have at least 4 page due to only 5 row selected per page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitPg()
{
window.location = "report.php?selpg=" + document.AllIn.cbxpg.value;
}
</script>
<?php
if(!isset( $_GET["selpg"]))
{    $selpg = 1; }
elseif ($_GET["selpg"] >= 1)
{    $selpg = $_GET["selpg"]; }
else
{    $selpg = 1; }
$selpgQQ = $selpg - 1;
$selpgQ1 = $selpgQQ * 5;
$selpgQ2 = $selpg * 5;
$no = $selpgQ1 +1;
?>
<html>
<body>
<table id="tabel" border="1" cols="30" width="50%" bordercolor="blue" >
    <tr bgcolor="gray">
        <th width="1%">No</th>
        <th width="1%">Date</th>
        <th width="1%">Time</th>
        <th width="2%">Number</th>
        <th width="10%">Message</th>


    </tr>
    <?

    $no = 1;
    $query =("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT $selpgQ1 , 5");
    $sql = mysql_query($query);

while ($hasil = mysql_fetch_array ($sql))    {
        $date = $hasil["date"];
        $time = $hasil["time"];
        $phone = $hasil["phone"];
        $message = $hasil["message"];
?>
        <tr >
        <td><center><?=$no?></center></td>
        <td><?=$date?></td>
        <td><?=$time?></td>
        <td><?=$phone?></td>
        <td><?=$message?></td>
        </tr>    

    <? $no++; }?>
<form name="AllIn" id="AllIn">
<select name="cbxpg" onchange="submitPg()">
<option value="0">Current Page : <?php echo $selpg; ?></option>
<option value="1">Page 1</option>
<option value="2">Page 2</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Please use *understandable* names for your variables when asking questions here; `$selpgQQ`??? Using this kind of names for your variables makes your code very hard to read and understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. This does not hardcode the number of rows to show on a single page, so is easier to customise later on. You can even make the number of pages editable with another select menu if you want! Follow the comments. I think you should check the bounds on 'selpg' on both sides: it could either be nonpositive, or exceed the number of pages.

```
<?php

// Set the number of rows to display on one page
$rowsPerPage = 5;

// Get the total number of rows in the table
$rowsTotal = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable"));

// To get the total number of pages, take the ceiling
// of the total number of pages divided by the number
// of pages to show on a single page
$pagesTotal = ceil($rowsTotal / $rowsPerPage);

// Get the current page number
if (!isset($_GET['selpg'])) {
    $pageNumber = 1;
} else {
    $pageNumber = $_GET['selpg'];
    if ($pageNumber < 1) {
        $pageNumber = 1;
    } else if ($pageNumber > $pagesTotal) {
        $pageNumber = $pagesTotal;
    }
}

// Get the offset for the SQL query
$offset = ($pageNumber - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

// Set the iterator to start at the current offset
$no = $offset;
```

Then in your MySQL query you'd write:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";
```

Lastly, to make the dropdown fill dynamically:

```
<select name="selpg" onchange="submitPg()">
    <?php

    // To fill the dropdown dynamically, loop
    // from 1 to the total number of pages
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagesTotal; $i++) {
        echo "<option value='$i'";

        // Immediately select the current page
        if ($i == $pageNumber) echo " selected";

        echo ">Page " . $i . "</option>";
    } ?>
</select>
```

For the remainder of the code, you could use ':?>' for better readability. Also, you missed a closing `</table>` tag.

```
<table id="tabel" border="1" cols="30" width="50%" bordercolor="blue" >
    <tr bgcolor="gray">
        <th width="1%">No</th>
        <th width="1%">Date</th>
        <th width="1%">Time</th>
        <th width="2%">Number</th>
        <th width="10%">Message</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

    // Preparing the query with limit and offset in place
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage");

    while ($hasil = mysql_fetch_array($query)) :?>
        <tr>
            <td><center><?php echo $no++ ?></center></td>
            <td><?php echo $hasil['date'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $hasil['time'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $hasil['phone'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $hasil['message'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

To make the JavaScript pick up the value of the selected item (currently, using 'Page: 5' instead of '5' as value doesn't work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitPg() {
    var formById = document.forms["AllIn"];
    var selectMenu = formById.elements["selpg"];
    window.location = "report.php?selpg=" + selectMenu.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: the code does the job, but as i turn to page 2 for example, the table rows won't change, it stays like table row on page 1

Comment: That is weird. I've updated my answer with code that runs fine for me with one of the tables I have in my local database.

If this does not help, try echoing some of the variables with `echo` and see whether their values are what you expect them to be.

Specifically, you can output the whole SQL query you're using, and see whether the limit and offset are correct.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: This means the query is not well formed. Double check whether the table name is correct and that the column name is correct. Try doing an `echo "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";` and see whether it outputs it right. I only have to change 'mytable' to one of the table names in my DB, and 'date' to another column name, and see the results. As you see I don't use the `$sql` variable as in your example.

Comment: done edited. no error but i dont understand why the table row still  won't changes when i turns to page 2

does it have anything to do with the javascript? <script type="text/javascript">
function submitPg()
{
window.location = "smsreport.php?selpg=" + document.AllIn.cbxpg.value;
}
</script>

Comment: Could you post the code you have now into http://pastebin.com/ so I can look at it? Edit: Yes, it might very well have to do with Javascript. Take out the `'Page '` part from the PHP code, where I set up the loop in the select menu, leaving just `echo "$i</option>";`

Comment: try take a look [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1DHwiGTY) i've post the whole code here

Comment: I've updated the answer with JavaScript code at the bottom, this picks up the value correctly. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you so much! the code does perfectly well.

Comment: Glad to help! I'd appreciate it if you marked the answer as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the number of rows in the database and then divide by 5. Take the integer part and add 1 if the rest is greater than 0. So if you have 30 rows, you get 6 pages, if you have 31 rows, you get 7.

Once you have that you add the options to your dropdown using a loop.

Comment: how do i integrate looping based on this dropdown?

Comment: Look other answer. Use select count (*) in mysql to get the number of rows. Better performance